# Add Html content inside Html tag generated by linkAction call - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my website using PHP and Laravel, I'm using the method `Html::linkAction` to route various requests given. The linkAction then is converted to an `<a>` element. Suppose I want to add more html tags inside that `<a>` content, how to do this? Or, is there a way to do this using this method?

I tried just `{{ Html::linkAction('Controller@method', '<img src=..>'}}` but then it shows literally the whole string `<img src=..>` instead of the actual image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URL::action()` instead:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('Controller@method') }}"><img src=..></a>
```

See [this link](https://laravel.io/forum/06-26-2014-how-to-use-htmllinkaction-with-bootstrap-glyphs).